How to add a FROM_NAME to emails we send?
I have an application that is sending email through SendGrid API v3. We would like to add a from name to make the emails easier to identify in the users inbox. For example, having a from_name like My Application to go with the from_email support@application.com.
Our current Mail object:
Mail(
        from_email = EMAIL_CREDENTIAL['FROM_EMAIL'],
        to_emails = to_email,
        subject = subject,
        html_content = html_content,
        is_multiple=is_multiple
    )

When I try to add a name or from_name variable I get an error. I have not found any entries in SendGrid's API support. Is there a value to add so I can add a name?
For clarification, I am sending from a Django app (Python) using the SendGridAPIClient.

This question is similar to: Adding a name to the "from" field in SendGrid in Node.js. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@IObert These questions ARE NOT the same. First, my question is Python the question you referenced is Node.js. Second, if you read that question it is not using the same API method.

I'm not a user of the Python lib but it would work the same as done in this sample file

@IObert No, I am sending a Mail object. The question you referenced does not. Why are you trying to get my question shut down? If you don't know just keep scrolling.

As suggested I tried the format suggested by the "duplicate" question and received an error.

Not sure if you have already tried the below but this might be worth a try?
from_email=Email("My Application <support@application.com>"),


The lack of a space before the < is not a spam signal per se, but certainly not a professional look.

You are downvoting for an accidental miss space?

No, my downvote is for the first snippet which I don't believe is valid syntax at all.

What's your opinion on the second snippet?

With the added space it looks reasonable. I don't have direct experience with Sendgrid but that should at least work technically. Though I guess the OP would benefit from a solution where they can pass in these values as parameters.

No worries. I have edited the answer to at least give the OP something to try.

This worked, thank you!
